# Why does data/BSS size change in these different cases?

Tags: c++, size, elf

I'm learning about virtual memory management and memory allocation of process. And do some experiment about it. There are some confusing points as below:

**case1**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

After compile the code and run `size` with the binary and got the following output:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1985     640       8    2633     a49 main
```

**case2:**
Change the code to:

```
#include <iostream>

int global;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

and rebuild it and the size output is:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1985     640      16    2641     a51 main
```

Note: `data` memory part is not changed, but `bss` changed from `8` to `16`. *This result make sense to me, since `int global` define a uninitialized global variable.*

**case3:**
Then I change the code to:

```
#include <iostream>

int global = 5;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I initialized the global variable. And analyze the binary again:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1985     644       4    2633     a49 main
```

*This time, the change doen't make sense to me.* Compared to case1, **why `data` part increase by 4 bytes and `bss` part decrease by 4?**

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with virtual memory management or process memory allocation. It is about the behaviour of the linker, and the ELF format.

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy is caused by the linker, and how it decides to layout the binary. The G++ default linker on x86 (GNU `ld`).

To see the difference, let's compile your test cases in three different ways:

```
$ for x in *.cpp ; do g++ -g3 $x -o $x.ld.exe ; done                  # GNU ld
$ for x in *.cpp ; do g++ -g3 $x -o $x.gold.exe -fuse-ld=gold ; done  # gold
$ for x in *.cpp ; do g++ -g3 $x -o $x.gold.exe -fuse-ld=lld ; done   # lld
```

Now, the sizes are as follows:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1873     656       8    2537     9e9 test1.cpp.ld.exe
   1873     656      16    2545     9f1 test2.cpp.ld.exe
   1873     660       4    2537     9e9 test3.cpp.ld.exe

   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1877     656       2    2535     9e7 test1.cpp.gold.exe
   1877     656       9    2542     9ee test2.cpp.gold.exe
   1877     660       2    2539     9eb test3.cpp.gold.exe

   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1817     576       2    2395     95b test1.cpp.lld.exe
   1817     576       9    2402     962 test2.cpp.lld.exe
   1817     580       2    2399     95f test3.cpp.lld.exe
```

The behavior of the `bss` section can be explained as follows:

There are two or three variables to store in here (`completed.0`, possibly `global` and `std::__ioinit`). The two that are always there, have a size and alignment of 1 byte each. The global that is only there in case 2, has size and alignment of 4 bytes. This is why both `gold` and `lld` require 2 bytes for the `bss` section in cases 1 and 3. For case 2, the layout is such that `global` is stored in between the two single-byte values, which requires an additional 3 bytes of padding between the first 1-byte value and `global`.

Generally speaking, GNU `ld` does something similar, except it uses the `bss` section to also provide inter-section padding. In case 1 and 3, only 2 bytes of the `bss` section are actually used, while case 2 uses 9 bytes of the `bss` section. Since `data` grows by 4 bytes in case 3 and `bss` is layouted after `data`, 4 of these padding bytes are removed to keep the offset of the following sections aligned. This is also why the size of the `bss` section grows by 8 bytes rather than 4 upon introducing `global`: GNU `ld` ensures that the end of the section remains 8-byte aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The much shorter version is: `.bss` section is mapped to the zero page with copy-on-write — any variable that is *not* explicitly initialized, will be added to `.bss`, which does not actually exist on the ELF *file*, and is only going to be allocated when changing the content of one of its variables (I'm oversimplifying — the allocation happen per-page so there's more details with that).

When you give it a default value, it can't be mapped to the zero page: its value needs to be present in the ELF file itself, and mapped into memory (again, as copy-on-write, so if you then change the value, a new page gets allocated with the modified value of your variable). If you changed that to `const int global = 5;` it would have been added to `.rodata` and you would have seen the size of `.text` increase instead.

I've blogged about the `size` command in the past: https://flameeyes.blog/2008/12/01/for-elves-size-matters/